# Scanning Zebra Printed ZPL CODE-128 Barcode not returning single integer value for AI(37) but works if value is two integers?

Tags: barcode, zpl, gs1-128

I am trying to print a GS1-128 Barcode using ZPL and when I print this out for some reason everything prints fine except the number in the AI `(37)`, I get `3715` (the `4` is missing), if I change the `4` to a two char integer value such as `04` or `14` I am able to scan it in the barcode.

```
^BCN,390,N,N,N
^FD>;>8(02)19410525013094(37)4>8(15)200330>610BAT100^FS
```

The only issue is the system I am working with stores the value for AI 37 as integers, so if the QTY is 4 then it will print as a 4, but i am getting nothing at the moment.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Omeil

Comment: As per @Mark comment I did the following to fix, I changed to subset B for the qty so single digits appear. this is the completed line of ZPL ^FD>;>80219410525013094>6374>8>515200330>610BAT10020^FS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are manually selecting the numeric mode of code128, using `>;` at the start of the data field.  Numeric mode encodes *pairs* of digits into single codewords.  And unfortunately the printer silently drops any unpaired digits.

You must either zero-pad your data when in subset-C or switch to ZPL's automatic mode for code128, which does a good job at minimizing symbol length.  For your data, keep the `>;` start mode and then let the automatic-mode shift or latch to subset-B as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be replacing >8 with >6 for AI 37 to print quantities of single or odd digits! eg 4, 103, etc